# Why is my second scene in JavaFX not showing up?

Tags: java, javafx, scene

I have a JavaFX program that is supposed to switch between two scenes, the first works great, but the second scene (scene2) is empty and does not show the button I created, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //first scene
    Button btGenerate = new Button("Generate My First Scene!");
    btGenerate.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {primaryStage.setScene(scene2);});

    GridPane gPane = createTextFieldPane();
    gPane.add(btGenerate, 0, 6);
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(gPane, 600, 600);

    //second scene
    Button btReturn = new Button("Make a New Scene!");
    btReturn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {primaryStage.setScene(scene1);});

    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(btReturn);
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root, 600, 600, Color.LIGHTBLUE);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Switch Scenes!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.show();                

}
```

Comment: You do not refer to the scene you create in the `start` method in the handler to `btGenerate`. This scene is stored in a local variable, but you're refering to a field in the event hander for `btGenerate`.

Comment: @fabian btGenerate shows up, it is btReturn that does not

Comment: The comment was not about "showing up" but about using a value not shown in the code snippet you posted (`scene2` which is not declared as a local variable before using it in the lambda expression and can therefore only refer to a field, provided the lambda compiles)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to move the setOnAction on btGenerate to after declaring the scene 2

```
    btGenerate.setOnAction(e-> {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    });
```

This piece of code should be here:

```
    Group root = new Group();
    root.getChildren().add(btReturn);
    Scene scene2 = new Scene(root, 600, 600, Color.LIGHTBLUE);
    btGenerate.setOnAction(e-> {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene2);
    });
    primaryStage.setTitle("Switch Scenes!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
    primaryStage.show();
```

You were setting an empty scene, that's why is not working.